# Tkinter Entry.filepath crashing when a shortcut or an internet shortcut is given to it

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run my code, I can get any file filepath for further use and put it in the Entry box. When I try to get a filepath of a shortcut, another window opens up, saying "catastrophic error". The console remains quiet all the time. Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import *
import os
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()

def create_game():
    # Defining the function for choosing the filepath
    def add_data():
        root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="",title="Select A File",filetypes=((".EXE files", "*.exe"),("all", "*.*")))
        enter_filepath.insert(0,str(root.filename))
    

    enter_filepath = Entry(root,width=30)
    enter_filepath.pack()

    btn_filepath = Button(root,text="Choose file",command=add_data)
    btn_filepath.pack()

create_game()

root.mainloop()
```

This is what I'm getting:
[image: Catastrophic Failure]

Comment: why a function inside a function?

Comment: @Module_art why can't it be?

Comment: because there's no need for that

Comment: @Module_art but when I'm calling it from another py script it is easier to do so rather than having to put 30 different functions to call from this script

Comment: You shuld not do this "calling from another script", every GUI framework has his own loop.

Comment: @Module_art if so, then I will have 4k+ strings of code in one py file that I will have to look through to add anything/fix anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246661/discussion-between-lg--and-module-art).

Comment: but if you do understand all these things why is it so hard to change your code so it will run?

Comment: Do  you understand where this error message cames from?

Comment: From what I can see there isn't a way to fix it. The error comes from Windows explorer itself (not Tkinter). There seems to be [DereferenceLinks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.dereferencelinks) for .NET but I couldn't find any similar options for Tkinter.